# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index1

Tags: datagridview

```
 int n = Convert.ToInt32(GridProduct.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
int ill = GrdSubProduct.Rows.Count;

            if (GridProduct.Rows.Count > 1 && GridProduct.SelectedRows[0].Index != GridProduct.Rows.Count - 1)
            {

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Del_DeleteBySubProductID", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", GridProduct.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (i > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show(" Product Delete");

                GetProduct();

            }
```

help me............

Answer (score 0):

which line causes the exception? my guess is the first line because GridProduct.SelectedRows is null if you don't set SelectionMode to FullRowSelect which is not the default ...

MSDN:

> The SelectionMode property must be set to FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect for the SelectedRows property to be populated with selected rows.